# How to pass translation string in angular 5 directive as an attribute value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular-directive, ngx-translate

I have created one simple angular directive for `Read More`. To use that directive I have written following code

```html
<p [readMore]="profile?.profileSummary" [length]="100" 
   [showMoreText]="{{ 'SHOW_MORE' | translate }}" 
   [showLessText]="{{ 'SHOW_LESS' | translate }}">
{{profile?.profileSummary}}</p>
```

But this template is not getting parsed, as I am passing translation Key, as an attribute value but its working fine when I am passing the only string to it.

How can I pass translation key to the attribute value in the Angular directive?

Comment: I think the real question is where your directive is. I dont see it anywhere. All I can see is inputs. It's possible you are using the input attribute as directive selector. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @user3492940 In above case `readMore` is the directive, which I am using as an input attribute as the directive selector.

Comment: So then try the answer proposed by @Fetraij. Which is using property binding without interpolation: `[showMoreText]="'SHOW_MORE' | translate" `

Comment: @user3492940 Yeah, Its works! I already marked it as Accepted Answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it with property binding:

```
 [showMoreText]="'SHOW_MORE' | translate "
```

or using interpolation:

```
 showMoreText="{{ 'SHOW_MORE' | translate }}"
```

read the detail here in the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation) about property binding or interpolation

Comment: Property binding would be the way to go, makes no sense to go for interpolation in this case.